# Relations between base(abstract?) models in loopback.js

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I have "abstract" model called Post, which is base model for Question, Answer and Comment. Then I want to implement that user can like/dislike posts, so I made this relations:

Account :

```
  "relations": {
    "likes": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Post",
      "foreignKey": "accountId",
      "keyThrough": "postId",
      "through": "Like"
    }
  }
```

Post:

```
  "relations": {
    "likes": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Account",
      "foreignKey": "postId",
      "keyThrough": "accountId",
      "through": "Like"
    }
  }
```

Like:

```
  "relations": {
    "post": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Post",
      "foreignKey": "postId"
    },
    "account": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Account",
      "foreignKey": "accountId"
    }
  }
```

And now I have methods for making likes :

```
Question.likes.link({id: $scope.question.id, fk: Account.getCurrentId()},
        function successCb(value, responseHeaders){
          ...
        },
        function errorCb(error){
          ...
        }
      );
```

But, after that call in my database i have this situation:

```
[
  {
    "id": "55f9bc6d1cc13cf4378f42cd",
    "accountId": "55f7de1477d818c40f6646f2",
    "undefined": "55f95edfea24d97a1868f88e"
  }
]
```

why is key for postId undefined?

Comment: Why is the foreign key defined like this in Post:  "foreignKey": {"as":"postId"}? Instead of like the others "foreignKey":"postId"

Comment: Sorry for that, I edited the question now, but the result is same without that